# The more precise definition of differential $dx$ when defining $dy=f'(x)\Delta x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**[Edit] I think I made a logical mistake here and this question is flat out false, Please don't waste your time to give more answers.**

---

This might be a stupid question, but I'm kind of lost in the notations here.

After reading some articles and textbooks (for instance https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differential), I am start wondering if there is a better definition for $dx$

Given a differentiable function $y=f(x)$, I have
$$\Delta y=f'(x)\Delta x + o(x)$$
Then the differential $dy$ can be defined as
$$dy=f'(x)\Delta x$$
It seems then the differential $dx$ can be defined as:
$$dx=\Delta x$$
So far so good, but then I am suppose to have
$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f'(x)\Delta x}{dx}=\frac{f'(x)dx}{dx}=f'(x)$$
And during the middle of it I can get
$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0}\Delta x=dx=0 \ (????)$$

What mistakes have I made, and is there an equation that can define $dx$ more precisely just like $dy$ ?

Comment: That's not the modern point of view. The differential of a function $f$ at a point $x_0$ is simply  the best linear approximation of the function in some neighbourhood of $x_0$, in the sense of *asymptotic analysis*.  It is obvious that the differential of a linear function is this linear function itself. So the differential map of the identity map is the identity map. With the usual abuse of language identifying a function with the formula which defines it, $\mathrm d x$ is simply the identity map,  and $\mathrm df_{x_0}=f'(x_0)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: There is something called nonstandard analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) in which one formalizes the notion of infinitesimals. But I would guess that it is way too early for you to care about learning such topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern approach does not use infinitesimals, precisely because of such apparent inconsistencies: a positive infinitesimal is smaller than any positive real number, but not zero. The issue is that such a real number doesn't exist, so infinitesimals aren't real numbers. But all the limit laws are usually developed for real numbers only, so how are we supposed to work with infinitesimals when calculating limits, which is at the heart of calculus?

There are two solutions to this: either introduce a rigorous way to treat infinitesimals (this is called non-standard analysis, and I suppose most mathematicians never bother to dive deep into this theory), or just don't use infinitesimals. The latter is the standard approach.

In this approach, the symbols $\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy$ don't have any inherent meaning. They are only meaningful in combinations like $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ or $\int f(x)\mathrm dx$. Just like $\lim$ by itself has no meaning, but $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ has meaning, or the fraction bar $\frac{~}{~}$ has no meaning without a numerator and denominator. Here, $\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}:=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Full stop. No further explanations what the numerator and denominator in that expression mean, since they don't mean anything. Only the full expression carries meaning, and it can't be manipulated like a fraction. In particular, things like $f'(x)\mathrm dx$ have no meaning and shouldn't come up in a rigorous treatment.

There's a caveat: In differential geometry, we have things called differential forms, which we write as $\mathrm df$ or $\mathrm dx$. But these don't have a whole lot to do with what you probably imagine when thinking of infinitesimals, and probably noone calls them infinitesimals.

Comment: This is actually what I thought at the first place, but later I come across some articles and textbooks (such as https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differential) that gives the definition of $dy$ and $dx$, but in these articles $dx$ is simply the same as $\Delta x$, but I have always thought $dx\approx\Delta x$, which makes even more confused......

Comment: The issue is that there are *a lot* of sources which don't treat this subject rigorously. Which isn't a problem in and of itself, since that's done all the time. You probably didn't learn synthetic geometry in school, after all. A first introduction need not be rigorous. But calculus has the unique issue that the rigorous approach is very different from the usual intuitive approach, which makes the transition quite hard. But once you begin to ask the questions you do, you should start looking for a bit of rigor in your sources.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you might want to look for sources about analysis instead of calculus.

Comment: I'm not sure "there are two solutions" is a good answer, when the question itself describes a _third_ solution, namely to consider $dx$ and $dy$ to be the _linear approximations_ to the differences. It looks like this third solution is not all that common in pure mathematics, but my impression is that it has a larger following in applications (such as thermodynamics) where you have a bunch of variables that vary _together_ according to some rule but you want to stay flexible about _which_ of them are functions of the other ones.

Comment: @Troposphere That's essentially the differential geometric approach, which I'd put into the "not using infinitesimals" camp, because those linear approximations are special kinds of linear maps varying with the position on a manifold. They don't resemble numbers closely enough that I'd categorize them as infinitesimals (which I interpret as a special kind of number, still)